# UIImageView image or video

Tags: iphone, video, uiimageview, uiimage

I have UIImageView where I put images from url (database). But there is one problem: some urls are not images but links to youtube or some other site. Is it possible to add video to UIImageView ? How can I achieve that ?

HELP! Thanks.

Comment: UIImageView can only display images. If you can determine the URL you get from database is of you tube, then you can create thumbnail image from the video and show it in the UIImageView.

Comment: Maybe some example code ? Tnx

Answer (score 2):

UIImageView can only display images. but you can create thumb Image from video and display in imageview.you can set flag on database side like, if url is image then set flag=1 and if url is video then flag=2. or you can determine using extension. split extension from url.

and you can generate thumb image from video like..

```
    NSURL *videoURl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURl options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 60);
    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];

    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];
     [YourImageView setImage:img];
    [img release];
```